# How to create table from two existing tables

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am in Oracle SQL developer and trying to create a table from two existing tables.

The existing tables contain the records of 1 million from where we are creating this new table temporary and
T1.id and T2.id columns are having indexes.

The Create table query mentioned below is the one which I am using and it is taking around 2 hours to create the table for 1 million records.

I need to optimize this query to reduce the time for table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE temporary
    AS
        ( SELECT /*+ parallel (T1,8)(T2,8)*/
            T1.id,
            T2.name,
            T2.code    
        FROM
            TABLE1 T1,
            TABLE2  T2
        WHERE
                T2.id = T1.id
            AND T2.code IN ( 'TYPE', 'SYS' )
        );
```

I need to optimize this query to reduce the time for table creation.

Comment: Please post an execution plan. It's hard to guess what is wrong because this particular query should use index scan for `table1` and full table scan (or index range scan depending on indexes) with a hash join of both. Even on a laptop with millions of records in both tables it should not take hours to complete, which may indicate missing statistics (that may lead to wrongly guessed nested loops access)

Comment: You are using an outdated join syntax. It has been made redundand by the introduction of explicit joins (`from t1 inner join t1 on t2.id = t1.id`) in 1992. Oracle was very late to adopt this syntax in 2001, but that was still more than 20 years ago now. The recommended sysntax for the parallel hint has changed to a mere `/*+ parallel (8)*/` many years ago if I am not mistaken. Anyway, these points should not affect performance here. How selective are the codes? What percentage of table2 do you get by applying `WHERE code IN ( 'TYPE', 'SYS' )`?

Comment: Usually a column called ID would uniquely identify one row in the table, and we would never see `WHERE t2.id = t1.id`, because these are different tables (e.g. a product table and a seller table; if the product with ID 123 is a banana and the seller with ID 123 is Mr. Smith, this doesn't make Mr. Smith a banana). So, is one of your IDs a unique ID for its table? Maybe even both?

Comment: Why do you need to copy data between tables? Can't you just create a view?